# How to log out from Laravel via Sanctum SPA

Tags: laravel, csrf, laravel-sanctum

I have a Vue.js SPA (`app.example.com`) that communicates with a backend Laravel application (`accounts.example.com`). Authentication is handled by the Laravel application - if an unauthenticated user visits the SPA, they are redirected to the Laravel app to log in and then redirected back to the SPA.

The Laravel application has a `LoginController` that is using Laravel's built-in `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers` trait. Logging in works perfectly.

The problem I have is with logging out - I have a "Log out" button in the SPA that needs to log out the Laravel session.

In order to prevent denial-of-service via CSRF, Laravel's default logout route (in `routes/web.php` -- `Route::post('logout', [LoginController::class, 'logout'])`) only accepts `POST` requests, not `GET` requests. Additionally, the logout `POST` must contain the CSRF token in the `_token` field.

By default, I don't have access to the raw CSRF token in the SPA, only the encrypted version provided by `/sanctum/csrf-cookie`, so I can't just create a form and have Vue.js submit it. I also can't use axios to do the logout for the same reason.

I tried to add another route (in `routes/api.php`) like this so the same logout function will be called but the `api` middleware group is applied instead of the `web` middleware group:

```
Route::post('/logout', [\App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::class, 'logout']);
```

When I call this endpoint, I get an error:

```
Method Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard::logout does not exist.
```

How can I get this logout to work without disabling CSRF protection or enabling `GET` requets to logout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this discussion](https://github.com/laravel/sanctum/issues/87) in the Laravel Sanctum repository.

Based on that, I changed my route in `routes/api.php` like this:

```
Route::post('/logout', [\App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::class, 'logout'])
    ->middleware('auth:web');
```

This tells the logout API call use `SessionGuard` instead of `RequestGuard`, and resolves the issue.